# Mapview only works on expo client and close the application when built in apk

Tags: react-native-maps

import MapView, { Marker, PROVIDER_GOOGLE } from "react-native-maps"
  const Location = (props)=>{
    const { states } = useContext(Context)
    const place = states.place

```
  return(
    <ImageBackground
        style={{flex:1}}
        source={require('../../img/mypoint-wallpaper.jpg')}>
        <View style={styles.container}>            
            <MapView style={{
                width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
                height: Dimensions.get('window').height
                }}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                showsMyLocationButton={true}                    
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: place && place.latitude,
                    longitude: place && place.longitude,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.01,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.01
                }}>

                {
                    (place.latitude && place.longitude) ?
                    <Marker
                    title={place.nome}
                    coordinate={{
                        latitude:  place.latitude,
                            longitude: place.longitude
                        }}/>
                        : null
                }
            </MapView>                    
        </View>
    </ImageBackground>
)
```

}

Comment: i have the some problem, do you cant fix the problem??